# how to find diamond in graph by Spark graphx

Tags: spark-graphx, graphframes

I'm using GraphFrame in Spark GraphX. I tried to find the a diamond in my graph. My graph as following:

```
nodeA->nodeB->nodeD->nodeF
nodeA->nodeE->nodeD->nodeG
```

so we can know there is a diamond(quadrilateral) in the graph as `nodeA->nodeB(nodeE)->nodeD`.
Then I used the the following query syntax:

```
val motifs= graphFrame.find("(A)-[e1]->(B);(A)-[e2]->(C);(B)-[e3]->(D);(C)-[e4]->(D)").filter("A.id!=D.id")
val e2 = motifs.select("A","B","C","D")
e2.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

but the result was wrong, did I make mistake in the above query clause please?

Comment: .filter("B.id!=C.id") ?